# How to use Express response inside promise callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

If this question has been answered elsewhere, I apologize.  I have been stuck on this issue for the past few hours.  I have a simple nodejs application that accepts a message posted from the front end, calls an asynchronous service with the message, and returns the response.  Below is the code:

```
('#btn').click(function (e) {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "./api/text",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ text: message })
    })
    .done(function (res) {
        console.log('Never receiving response'); // Log never hit
        $('#msg_response').html(res);
    });
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.post("/api/text", function(request, response) {
  var message = request.body.text;

  var client = new Client();

  client.doSomethingAsync({
      data: message
  }, function (err, msg) {
      // Getting here, but never returning to 'done' above
      response.json(msg);
  });
});
```

The issue is that the response from the "post" request is never being received from the server.  I believe it has something to do with the response being sent in the callback function because if I take the response out of the callback, everything works great.  Is it possible to send the response back from an asynchronous call?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:  Updated to most recent code attempts.

Edit:  There have been some questions on how client.doSomethingAsync() works.  It simply sends the data passed in to a different service via HTTP request.  The response is then passed back to the callback.  I am confident that this method is functioning correctly because I am able to see the message being passed back as a response as well as verify the service is being called.

Edit:  Additional evidence that there is something strange happening in the callback.  The code below runs correctly and returns to the 'done' callback properly:

```
app.post("/api/text", function(request, response) {
  var message = request.body.text;

  var client = new Client();

  client.doSomethingAsync({
      data: message
  }, function (err, msg) {
      console.log(msg);  // logs a json object
  });

  response.json({ test: 'test' }); // Returns successfully
});
```

Comment: Or maybe `client.doSomethingAsync` never calls the second argument passed to it. What exactly does `client.doSomethingAsync` do and how does it work?

Comment: also you don't need `response.end()` - `response.json()` takes care of ending the response by itself

Comment: I have debugged client.doSomethingAsync and seen that msg is populated.  Also, no exceptions or errors are getting thrown so I know the response object is ok.  It's just that after the callback is finished no response is received on the front end.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas Kyriakides.  I don't think that will solve my problem but I will remove it.

Comment: 2nd - `response.json` takes an object not a string. So remove that `JSON.stringify` and just pass your `msg`. Then remove the `debugger` from your client code and try again. You might be getting your response back just fine but your client code fails

Comment: I have attempted your suggestion but still not receiving the response.  It's as if the "done" is never called.

Comment: if you do a `console.log(msg)` just above your `response.json(msg)` line, what does it log?

Comment: You mention in your title 'promise callback'. Is 'doSomethingAsync' promise based? If so, should you be using `.then` instead of a callback? Explain what you mean by promise callback.

Comment: It returns an object containing information related to the service I am calling.  The object is small and doesn't contains a handful of key value pairs.  Even if I replace `response.json(msg)` with `response.json({ test: 'test' })` the code still doesn't return.

Comment: @ABondi415 I think the issue is with the function on client. Do you have the code to tell us what this function is?

Comment: This is the method definition for 'doSomethingAsync()': `client.doSomethingAsync(args: any, callback?: client.RequestCallback) => Q.Promise<any>`.  The RequestCallback gets invoked upon completion of the method.  I will look for the code on the client, but it is from a third party API, not something I created.

Comment: "returns to the 'done' callback"?

Comment: I am making an ajax request to my nodejs server: `$.ajax().done(function(res) {});`  This callback is never being invoked.  It's as though the `response.json()` isn't resolving the promise.

Comment: Is the `app.post(...)...` snippet supposed to be an alternative to the `$.ajax(...)...` part of the first snippet? If so it would be less confusing to include the `('#btn').click(function (e) {...})` wrapper.

Comment: No, `app.post(...)...` is the snippet that is called by the `$.ajax(...)...` code.  The execution flow should be:`$.ajax(...)` -> `app.post(...)` -> `client.doSomethingAsync(...)` -> `client.doSomethingAync(...)` callback -> `$.ajax(...)` callback